# read names in stringList

Tags: java, arraylist

I wanted to print a list of names from the arrayList:

```
public class arrReader {
static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
static ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Please enter your names: ");
    String names = input.next();
    while(names.length()>0) {
        arr.add(names);
        names = input.nextLine();
    }

    PrintArry();
}


public static void PrintArry() {
    System.out.println("------------------------------------");
    for (String i : arr) {
        System.out.println(i);

    }
}

}
```

the result is:
Please enter your names: 
Apple Banana Peace

---

Apple

Banana Peace

how do I get the name display in one line?
Also why do I have to enter twice to get the result?
thanks!

Comment: Your problem is caused by fact that `next()` takes only one token, so for data like `Apple Banana Peace[enter/line-separatpr]` it will take only `Apple`. After that `nextLine()` will read remaining part of string until line separator (here ` Banana Peace` as next value). But since that string has more that 0 characters your loop will ask you for another string and will not stop until you enter empty line. If you want to read that data as *one string* containing `Apple Banana Peace` so you could print it as one value in one line you need `nextLine()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try:

```
System.out.print(i);
```

instead of:

```
System.out.println(i);
```

The method println prints i and afstand a new line

Answer (score 1):

To NOT add "," after last one.

```
if (arr.size() > 0) {
    System.out.print(arr.get(0));
    for (int i = 1; i < arr.size(); i++) {
        System.out.print(", " + arr.get(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if you use JAVA 8, you can try with this:

```
public static void PrintArry() {
    System.out.println("------------------------------------");
    Arrays.stream(arr).forEach(System.out::print);
}
```